# -Xpkginfo:always arguments causes javac 1.7.0_25 to crashes

Tags: java, javac

### My goal

We need to pass `-Xpkginfo:always` arguments to `javac` compiler.  We are using `javac 1.7.0_25`.  `-Xpkginfo` is available for this version says [java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html).

1. *Expected result*: `package-info.class` files shall be generated
2. *Actual result* : `javac` compiler is crashing :

`An exception has occurred in the compiler (1.7.0_25). Please file a bug at the Java Developer Connection (http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport)  after checking the Bug Parade for duplicates. Include your program and the following diagnostic in your report.  Thank you.`

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.visitTopLevel(Enter.java:291)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCCompilationUnit.accept(JCTree.java:459)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.classEnter(Enter.java:258)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.classEnter(Enter.java:272)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.complete(Enter.java:484)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.main(Enter.java:469)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.enterTrees(JavaCompiler.java:929)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:824)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:439)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:353)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:342)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:333)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.Main.compile(Main.java:76)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.Main.main(Main.java:61)
```

### What I've tried so far

It works with java 1.8, but unfortunately, we can't upgrade our java compiler because we still have old java code.

### EDIT

Used `javac -X` to make sure `1.7.0_25` has `-Xpkginfo` argument available.  Answer is yes :

```
PS C:\SVN\products\faa_mx\vs2017.install2> javac -X
  -Xlint                     Enable recommended warnings
  -Xlint:{all,cast,classfile,deprecation,dep-ann,divzero,empty,fallthrough,finally,options,overrides,path,processing,rawtypes,serial,static,try,unchecked,varargs,-cast,-classfile,-deprecation,-dep-ann,-divzero,-empty,-fallthrough,-finally,-options,-overrides,-path,-processing,-rawtypes,-serial,-static,-try,-unchecked,-varargs,none} Enable or disable specific warnings
  -Xbootclasspath/p:<path>   Prepend to the bootstrap class path
  -Xbootclasspath/a:<path>   Append to the bootstrap class path
  -Xbootclasspath:<path>     Override location of bootstrap class files
  -Djava.ext.dirs=<dirs>     Override location of installed extensions
  -Djava.endorsed.dirs=<dirs> Override location of endorsed standards path
  -Xmaxerrs <number>         Set the maximum number of errors to print
  -Xmaxwarns <number>        Set the maximum number of warnings to print
  -Xstdout <filename>        Redirect standard output
  -Xprint                    Print out a textual representation of specified types
  -XprintRounds              Print information about rounds of annotation processing
  -XprintProcessorInfo       Print information about which annotations a processor is asked to process
  -Xprefer:{source,newer}    Specify which file to read when both a source file and class file are found for an implicitly compiled class
  -Xpkginfo:{always,legacy,nonempty} Specify handling of package-info files
```

Also tried with 1.7.0_80, same crash :
`An exception has occurred in the compiler (1.7.0_80).`

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.visitTopLevel(Enter.java:291)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCCompilationUnit.accept(JCTree.java:459)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.classEnter(Enter.java:258)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.classEnter(Enter.java:272)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.complete(Enter.java:484)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.main(Enter.java:469)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.enterTrees(JavaCompiler.java:929)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:824)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:439)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:353)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:342)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:333)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.Main.compile(Main.java:76)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.Main.main(Main.java:61)
```

### Alternative solution

Would that make sense to use `javac 1.8` and use the command line `javac -source 1.7 -target 1.7 MyClass.java`?

Comment: Run the command `javac -X` and see if `-Xpkginfo` appears in the output. If it doesn't then it is not supported. If you can't upgrade to JDK 1.8, maybe try a later version of JDK 1.7 where the bug may have been fixed. Maybe try [7u80](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase7-521261.html).

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash Reading this :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22610400/can-program-developed-with-java-8-be-run-on-java-7.  Could I do something like this `javac -source 1.7 -target 1.7 MyClass.java` ?.  The poster says it is not recommended.  We have drools 5.6 in our project.  It is quite old

Comment: @Abra Post updated.  `-Xpkginfo` appears in the output for 7u25.  Also tried 7u80, I have same crash.  Would it be possible to use `javac` 1.8 with `-source 1.7` and `-target 1.7`?  Would that make sense at all?

Answer (score 0):

With java 1.7, it looks like that if you pass `-Xpkginfo:always` to `javac`, it only accepts `package-info.java` empty files.  If you pass non-empty files, we get the crash.

With 1.8, `javac` is able to deal with empty and non empty files in one command line.

So, the workaround with 1.7 is to call `javac` multiple time, once with all empty `package-info.java` files, and another time with non-empty files.